# iPhone scroll-wheel picker for <select> menus

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview, menu

I'm developing a UIWebView iPhone app and mobile website and within the app I have many `<select>` menus that contain 100+ items each!

I was wondering if there is a way to break the `<select>` menu into submenus in order to make it easier for iPhone users to make selections, ex:

I have this for my database setup:

```
                   |   Subcategory     |      Food      |
                   --------------------------------------
                   |eggs and cheese    |scrambled       |
                   |breakfast cereal   |frosted flakes  |
                   |breakfast cereal   |mini wheats     |
                   |breakfast cereal   |cherrios        |
```

So each item has a "sub-category" and then the actual "food"

I print that into dropdowns like this:

```
<select class="breakfast">
  <option value="100" rel="20">Breakfast Cereal (Frosted Flakes)</option>
  <option value="200" rel="10">Breakfast Cereal (Cheerios)</option>
  <option value="150" rel="25">Breakfast Cereal (Mini Wheats)</option>
  <option value="300" rel="30">2 Eggs and Cheese (scrambled)</option>
</select>
```

And when I touch the dropdown on the iPhone to make a selection, all 4 options are listed in that scroll wheel UI that iPhone defaults to:

[image]

I would somehow like to set it up so that I can have 2 scroll wheels with the Subcategories on the left and then once you pick that, it gives you the options for "food" on the right, like this (but with only 2 wheels):

[image]
<sub>(source: [iphoneized.com](https://iphoneized.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/spinning-wheel.jpg))</sub>

This example would be a scroll wheel on the left with 2 options, `Eggs and Cheese` and `Breakfast Cereals`, then when the user touches `Breakfast Cereals`, it would load the 3 cereal options into the scroll wheel picker UI on the right!

This is a little complicated, but does anyone have experience with this, or is it even possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem here: [Add a search function to UIPickerView in Xcode, or open <select> menu in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061079/add-a-search-function-to-uipickerview-in-xcode-or-open-select-menu-in-uitable/12451423#12451423)

I filter the results outside of the app, through the website using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

https://github.com/arkichek/AFPickerView

Comment: this doesn't really help with a uiwebview app unfortunately... and I'm using `<select>` menu tags to create these menus...