# Add a search function to UIPickerView in Xcode, or open <select> menu in UITableView

Tags: iphone, xcode, search, webview, uipickerview

Is it possible to add a search bar to look up values in the UIPickerView generated by a `<select>` menu tag?

I have a UIWebView app that has `<select>` menus with 100+ `<option>` tags and the iPhone opens a UIPickerView, but it's kind of hard to choose an option, I thought a search bar would be the easiest way!

My original question with database details: [iPhone scroll-wheel picker for <select> menus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060498/iphone-scroll-wheel-picker-for-select-menus/12060529)

**EDIT: or is it possible to make the iPhone open `<select>` menus in a UITableView rather than UIPickerView????**

Comment: Do you need a UIPickerView custom with a search bar inside or filter the picker view elements with a external search bar?

Comment: Did you consider to use a UITableView to show the options?

Comment: @LuisEspinoza I'm using a pretty much full screen UIWebView app, and I have `<select>` menus that open by default in the UIPickerView, I just maybe wanted to add a search bar on the top of the default picker where it would sort based on search terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of filtering via the app, I decided to use this: http://www.lessanvaezi.com/filter-select-list-options/

This way uses a text `input` to filter the results using jQuery.